# Displaying an image on a JtextArea within a JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing

not sure why this won't work i am using netbeans to create it i have similar code in jcreator an it works. any help greatly appreciated

```
    public void BoardGUI(){
         panel = new JPanel();
         setIconImage(new ImageIcon("images/die.bmp").getImage());

         Container cPane;
         cPane = getContentPane();
         cPane.setBackground(Color.red);

         setTitle("ITT Game Of Life");
         setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         panel.setOpaque(false);                         //the frame
         setSize(800,650);
         setLocation(500,100);
         boardArea = new JTextArea(50,100)  {

         ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon( "/images/Board.jpg" );

     @Override
     public void paint( Graphics g ) {
        g.drawImage( image.getImage(), 0, 0, this);
        super.paint(g);
     }
   };

   boardArea.setOpaque(false);
   boardArea.setEditable(true);
   boardArea.setBounds(100,50,200,200);
   cPane.add(boardArea);
```

Comment: Do you get any error? What exactly doesn't work? When I tried it I can see the image as background of text area.

Comment: no error comes up, just when i run it i am not getting the images to apper at all. should i have the images located in with the classes or in a folder somewhere else within the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setIconImage(new ImageIcon("images/die.bmp").getImage()); 

ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon( "/images/Board.jpg" );
```

You used 2 different ways to spcify the location of the image. I would guess the first is correct. Did your frame icon change?

Also, the [How to Use Icons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) tutorial gives better examples by the the image as a resource.

Comment: i have it. thanks it was its actual location within netbeans that was the problem. i ve moved the file and gave it its full location so thats fine now. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the location of image folder for netbeans. I used to use netbeans in my student life. The thing I can remembered, it might be the issue with relative path to the images.

That might be the reason to not work with netbeans only.