# Display an image in JTextArea

Tags: java, image, swing, chat, jtextarea

I am trying to write a chat client(multi-threaded) which should be capable of displaying images(sent by server) in the main chat window(JTextArea in my case)? Is there any way to do this directly or do I have to encode and parse back my image. For example Facebook chat lets you directly drag and drop images and displays them in main chat window. If we cannot do this in Java, please suggest some other Environment in which this is doable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092491/displaying-an-image-on-a-jtextarea-within-a-jpanel

Comment: I'm not sure you can go this with JTextArea, but you can with JTextPane, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675482/insert-a-picture-into-a-jtextpane-by-clicking-insert) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993424/how-to-add-images-in-jtextpane) for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a JTextPane would suit your needs better: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
JTextPane t = new JTextPane();
t.setContentType("text/html");
t.setText("<html><img src='" + Hello.class.getClassLoader().getResource("hello.gif").toString() + "'/></html>");
```